# Is there an electron documentation for VSCode?

Tags: documentation, visual-studio-code, electron

Is there any way to load up the electron documentation so that VSCode can, show the electron suggestions when I start typing a new word, and show the comments of each function and its parameter when I hover over it.

I couldn't find an electron extension on VSCode that does that.

Comment: If you using Mac you can use Dash (https://kapeli.com/dash) and install the plugin for VSCode.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the electron typings files (`electron.d.ts`). This file is included in recent versions of electron you get through npm and the typings file should be picked up automatically when you import or require `electron`.

[image]

If you are using an up to date version of electron but still don't see the proper intellisense, please file an new issue with a small sample project description and I'll take a look: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: I installed the typings using `typings install electron --source dt --global` but they only work when the typings file is open

Comment: You should try just using the typings that come with electron when you `npm install electron`. Those typings get picked up automatically. Otherwise you'll have to create a [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig)  to make sure all the js and d.ts files are part of the same project

Comment: I was trying `npm install electron-prebuilt` instead of `npm install electron`. In the end both cloning a test repo from electron worked as well as the`npm install electron`